# How to Code a Sparrow-like Side Navigation Menu with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, css, mobile-safari

If anybody is familiar with the Sparrow iOS app I'm looking for a tutorial or just an idea of how I could approach building a similar method in HTML5/CSS3/jQuery. I included 3 screenshots below directly from the app so you can get an idea of what I'm talking about..

Of course the jQuery functionality may not be able to perfectly mimic iOS animations and such. But I'm hoping that the functionality could be similar, i.e. you tap the top left button and our 1st nav menu appears. You can then tap on the old screen to bring it back into view, or use the other back button to slide into a 2nd nav window.

here are the screens for reference - thanks in advance for any help!

[image: default screen]
[image: first sliding nav]
[image: 2nd sub-menu slider]

Comment: Have you looked at Bootstrap and jQuery Mobile?

Comment: @Ivan hey no I've only looked into jQuery Mobile and it's not exactly what I was looking for. I've never used Bootstrap before - it looks like it was put out by Twitter? I guess my issue is that I don't know what to call this type of navigation since it's really only useful on mobile devices. never seen it implemented anywhere than iOS, and one website http://mobile.deckfifty.com/

Comment: @JakeRocheleau, did you finally find out something?

Comment: @PavelDaynyak over time I still haven't found any good solutions. iOS just has a faster library of code so the animations are more crisp than using jQuery. I hope to eventually find some method with HTML5/CSS3/JS.

Comment: I've written a script to do this, but its pretty bespoke. If you still are looking for an answer to this I can unpick it and post something up here that you could use though. I have been meaning to make it more generic for a while anyway. Let me know if that it is still something you are looking for.